# CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217 - cURL Microsoft Graph API

Tags: curl, microsoft-graph-api

Trying to get a sharepoint download url link from the Microsoft graph using cURL for MacOS only.

I have an application id, and client secret setup in the azure portal with permissions set.
I was able to get an authorization token but when I try to use that token I keep getting an error.
Here is the code:

```
json=$(curl -d 'client_id'='APPLICATIONID' \
-d 'scope'='https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
-d 'client_secret'='CLIENTSECRETVALUE' \
-d 'grant_type'='client_credentials' \
 'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT/oauth2/token') \
&& token=$(echo $json | sed "s/{.*\"access_token\":\"\([^\"]*\).*}/\1/g") \
&& echo "token = $token"

curl -H "Host:graph.microsoft.com" \
-H "Authorization:Bearer=$token" \
-H "X-Cookie:token=$token" \
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/sites/SPECIFICSHAREPOINTSITEID/drive/root:/CCPackage_Install.pkg.zip?select=id,@microsoft.graph.downloadUrl"
```

But I keep getting back an error:

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidAuthenticationToken","message":"CompactToken parsing failed with error code: 80049217","innerError":{"date":"2021-07-20T23:22:57","request-id":"45f59601-143e-4fee-af13-changingsomeofthis","client-request-id":"45f59601-143e-4fee-af13-changingsomeof this"}}}
```

What did I try:
I tried both the `2.0` and `1.0` endpoints for the token but I got the same error.

I also tried the last curl command alone and got the same error so maybe I didn't write the second curl command correctly?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

First off there should be no equal sign when assigning the Authorization header. Should be *-H "Authorization:Bearer $token" *

Second you should be using *https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token* endpoint

Below is a version from your code that does what you are trying to do. Note I have replaced the Graph endpoint to test the code.

```
json=$(curl -d 'client_id'='CLIENT_ID' \
-d 'scope'='https://graph.microsoft.com/.default' \
-d 'client_secret'='CLIENT_SECRET' \
-d 'grant_type'='client_credentials' \
'https://login.microsoftonline.com/TENANT_ID/oauth2/v2.0/token') \
&& token=$(echo $json | sed "s/{.*\"access_token\":\"\([^\"]*\).*}/\1/g") \
&& echo "token = $token"

curl -H "Host:graph.microsoft.com" \
-H "Authorization:Bearer $token" \
-H "X-Cookie:token=$token" \
"https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure $token is an access token and not a refresh_token.  If you get a different error about invalid or expired access token, you need to make an http POST request with grant_type=refresh_token and refresh_token={yourRefreshToken} and then you will get a json response which contains a valid access token which you can then use in the Authorization:Bearer {yourNewAccessToken} header.